# How to count incrementally in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I am assigned a problem which I am not sure how to solve in SQL Server (version 5/8). Here is the simple query and its output:

```
Select location, date_time, Item_sold
From Product

Location        Date_time                   Item_sold
VA            12/10/2010 1:30:00 PM           Candy
VA            12/10/2010 3:30:00 PM           Chips
VA            12/13/2010 12:50:00 AM          Wine
DC            12/13/2010 8:00:00 AM           Gum
DC            12/13/2010 12:30:00 PM          Bags
DC            12/13/2010 1:16:00 PM           Cheese
DC            12/13/2010 12:00:00 AM          Hotdog
NJ            12/14/2010 12:00:00 AM          Coffee
NJ            12/14/2010 1:15:00 PM           Beers
NJ            12/14/2010 12:00:00 AM          Coffee
NJ            12/14/2010 1:45:00 PM           Water
```

Here is my desired output, which I guess a while/for loop or a pivot function could do the job but my experience is not there yet. Basically, I need to count the number of item sold from the Item_sold column incrementally (base line date starts from 12/8 to 12/9, 12/8 to 12/10, 12/8 to 12/11, 12/8 to 12/12...)

```
Location    12/10 to 12/11  12/10 to 12/12  12/10 to 12/13  12/10 to 12/14
VA               2             2                  3              3
DC               0             0                  3              3 
NJ                 0             0                  0              4
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I think your 12/8 - 12/11 and 12/8 - 12/12 should be 2 for VA, isn't it?

Comment: @joe - can you confirm that it should have a row for NJ, and that VA is not supposed to be 0/0/2/2/2/3?  Why are there 0's between 2 and 3?

Comment: And the query should be dynamic?

Comment: @joe - Why are there exactly 6 columns for that matter, will you supply a date range?

Comment: @cyberkiwi, yes it should be a row for NY but I only showed VA and DC as a example. date range is 12/8/10 to 1/5/11.

Answer (score 2):

Sample table and data

```
create table Product(Location char(2), Date_time datetime, Item_sold varchar(20))
insert Product select 'VA', '20101210 1:30:00 PM' ,'Candy'
insert Product select 'VA', '20101210 3:30:00 PM' ,'Chips'
insert Product select 'VA', '20101213 12:50:00 AM' ,'Wine'
insert Product select 'DC', '20101213 8:00:00 AM' ,'Gum'
insert Product select 'DC', '20101213 12:30:00 PM' ,'Bags'
insert Product select 'DC', '20101213 1:16:00 PM' ,'Cheese'
insert Product select 'DC', '20101213 12:00:00 AM' ,'Hotdog'
insert Product select 'NJ', '20101215 12:00:00 AM' ,'Coffee'
insert Product select 'NJ', '20101215 1:15:00 PM' ,'Beers'
insert Product select 'NJ', '20101215 3:45:00 AM' ,'Cream'
```

The T-SQL to produce the results required

```
declare @start datetime
declare @end datetime
select @start = '20101208', @end = '20110105'

declare @sql nvarchar(max);
-- generate the column names
select @sql = coalesce(@sql + ',', '') + QuoteName(Convert(char(5),@start,101)+' - '+Convert(char(5),DT,101))
from (
    select @start + number DT
    from master..spt_values
    where type='P' and number between 0 and DATEDIFF(D,@start,@end)) T;

-- replace the column names into the generic PIVOT form
set @sql = REPLACE('
;with COUNTS AS (
    select p.location, Convert(char(5),@start,101)+'' - ''+Convert(char(5),@start + v.number,101) DT, X.C
    from 
    (
        Select distinct location From Product
        where Date_time >= @start and Date_time < @end+1 -- * the date after, to handle the times
    ) p
    inner join master..spt_values v on v.type=''P'' and v.number between 0 and DATEDIFF(D,@start,@end)
    cross apply
    (
        select COUNT(*) C from product p2
        where p2.Location=p.Location
        and p2.date_time >= @start and p2.date_time < @start + v.number +1
    ) X
)
select location, :columns:
from COUNTS p
pivot (max(C) for DT in (:columns:)) pv',
':columns:', @sql)

-- execute for the results
exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@start datetime,@end datetime', @start, @end
```

Comment: Thank you, testing your script now. I also updated the output just to make it more understandable. One question for you, suppose i create a temp table with with a larget set of data (date range from 10/1/09 to 10/1/10) would your script work?

Comment: I just executed the script and couple error occured. Here are script error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'inner'.  Incorrect syntax near 'X'.

Comment: @joe - I just copied and pasted both blocks into ssms as is and ran it in tempdb an it gave the results without error. Is that what you did? Can you confirm the SQL Server version is >= 2005?

Comment: It's MS SQL Server 2000/5/8 version. Thanks for your other advice.

Answer (score 0):

The above, from cyberkiwi, is too complicated. You need to do something called a 'table rotation'. Assuming you have a product table like this:

```
create table product
(
  location  char(2)     not null ,
  date_time datetime    not null ,
  item_sold varchar(32) not null ,

  primary key clustered ( location , date_time ) ,
)
```

The sql you want is the following SELECT statement:

```
select Location       = loc.location  ,
       "12/8"         =  t8.sales_cnt ,
       "12/8 - 12/09" =  t9.sales_cnt ,
       "12/8 - 12/10" = t10.sales_cnt ,
       "12/8 - 12/11" = t11.sales_cnt ,
       "12/8 - 12/12" = t12.sales_cnt ,
       "12/8 - 12/13" = t13.sales_cnt
from      ( select distinct location from #product ) loc
left join ( select location , sales_cnt = count(*) from #product where date_time between '2011-12-08 00:00:00.000' and '2011-12-08 23:59:59.997' group by location ) t8  on t8.location  = loc.location
left join ( select location , sales_cnt = count(*) from #product where date_time between '2011-12-08 00:00:00.000' and '2011-12-09 23:59:59.997' group by location ) t9  on t9.location  = loc.location
left join ( select location , sales_cnt = count(*) from #product where date_time between '2011-12-08 00:00:00.000' and '2011-12-10 23:59:59.997' group by location ) t10 on t10.location = loc.location
left join ( select location , sales_cnt = count(*) from #product where date_time between '2011-12-08 00:00:00.000' and '2011-12-11 23:59:59.997' group by location ) t11 on t11.location = loc.location
left join ( select location , sales_cnt = count(*) from #product where date_time between '2011-12-08 00:00:00.000' and '2011-12-12 23:59:59.997' group by location ) t12 on t12.location = loc.location
left join ( select location , sales_cnt = count(*) from #product where date_time between '2011-12-08 00:00:00.000' and '2011-12-13 23:59:59.997' group by location ) t13 on t13.location = loc.location
order by 1
```

Comment: and without getting too complicated, how will your code scale for a variable range of dates? I have always disliked the BETWEEN + 'xxx 23:59:59.997' method, especially since you can now get dates closer to midnight in SQL Server 2008. Less-than-next-day seems to work best and accurately represents the condition.

Comment: thanks. this works for the sample data above but how would you do when you have a larger set of data?