# how to count products from a based date and add one date after that

Tags: sql, sql-server

Yesterday I posted a question about a problem i need to solve in SQL Server 2005/2008. There were some answer that were useful but they were written much advanced than my experience. I have updated the desired output:

```
select state, date_time, item sold
from product
```

Below is the **sample** data only. Actual date range is 12/10/2010 to 01/15/2011.

```
    ----------------------------------------------------------
    State         |  Date_time           |     Item_sold
    ----------------------------------------------------------
    VA             12/10/2010 1:30:00 PM        Candy
    VA             12/10/2010 3:30:00 PM        Chips
    VA             12/13/2010 12:50:00 AM       Wine
    DC             12/13/2010 8:00:00 AM        Gum
    DC             12/13/2010 12:30:00 PM       Bags
    DC             12/13/2010 1:16:00 PM        Cheese
    DC             12/13/2010 12:00:00 AM       Hotdog
    NJ             12/14/2010 12:00:00 AM       Coffee
    NJ             12/14/2010 1:15:00 PM        Beers
    NJ             12/14/2010 3:45:00 AM        Cream
    NJ             12/14/2010 1:45:00 PM        Water
```

Is there a way in SQL server that can count the products sold in each state starts from

> 12/10/2010 to 12/11/2011; 12/10/2010
>   to 12/12/2010; 12/10/2010 to
>   12/13/2010; 12/10/2010 to 12/14/2010;
>   12/10/2010 to 12/15/2010...?

the sample output would be:

```
State 12/10 to 12/11    12/10 to 12/12  12/10 to 12/13  12/10 to 12/14
VA     2               2                 3                3
DC     0               0                 3                3 
NJ      0               0                 0                4
```

Thanks a gain, folks.

Comment: How many columns do you want?

Comment: Do you know up front what all of your date ranges are, or do you need to build them into the same query?

Comment: @Quassnoi, data range would be 12/1/2010 to 1/15/2011. Thanks.

Comment: @Kyle date range would be 12/1/2010 to 1/15/2011. Would like to display all the columns in this date range and build into the same query. Thanks.

Comment: @joe: so you want `46` columns? If the data range changes, shall the number of the columns change as well?

Comment: Very strange request. You will see the total aggregated sales for each day from the starting date. You will see exponentially growing numbers even if your sales are dropping. What would it be useful for?

Comment: @Joe, it sounds like you don't know up front all of your date ranges given your response to @Quassnoi's question.  A year from now, won't you have hundreds of columns?  And if so, how useful is the data?  If I were you, I think I'd return simpler data from sql and have my script that called the query do the date a-to-date b sum aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head something like:

```
SELECT State, convert(varchar,Date_Time,101) as Period, count(item_sold)
FROM YourTable
Group By State, Period
Order by Period, State
```

If you want the format shown above have a look at the [T-SQL Pivot statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx)

Comment: The problem with this solution is that the asker wants "aggregatedly" growing time ranges. The first is 1 day, then 2-days, then 3-days, each interval starting the same day. Therefore every row should be able to appear multiple times in the result set.

Comment: @Dercsa, the date range would generally be 2 to 4 weeks. Would this still present a problem?

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest creating a table of dates or numbers (often called a tally table).

You would have to do this with dynamic SQL to handle the changing output schema.

Use that in combination with a dynamic pivot technique [often discussed here on SO](http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+sql+dynamic+pivot).

Answer (score 0):

You have a complex requirement that require a complex query. I really don't see a "simple" alternative for such requirements. I would suggest working through [How to count incrementally in SQL SERVER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684660/how-to-count-incrementally-in-sql-server) (your original question)

Answer (score 0):

I can't see when you would really want to do dynamic columns to that level. I can see if you have a variable number of statuses, between  3 and 10 or something, and you wanted that. But this will grow with a column for every day past the begin date if I understand correctly, which can't be what you want.

That being said, here is a solution which would allow you to have multiple columns with different specified date ranges cleanly. Let me know what you think.

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('ProductTest'))
    DROP TABLE ProductTest;
GO

CREATE TABLE ProductTest
(
    InState CHAR(2)
    , DateSold DATETIME2(1)
    , ItemSold VARCHAR(20)
);
GO

INSERT INTO ProductTest
VALUES ('VA',      '12/10/2010 1:30:00 PM',       'Candy')
    , ('VA',      '12/10/2010 3:30:00 PM',       'Chips')
    , ('VA',      '12/13/2010 12:50:00 AM',      'Wine')
    , ('DC',      '12/13/2010 8:00:00 AM',       'Gum')
    , ('DC',      '12/13/2010 12:30:00 PM',      'Bags')
    , ('DC',      '12/13/2010 1:16:00 PM',       'Cheese')
    , ('DC',      '12/13/2010 12:00:00 AM',      'Hotdog')
    , ('NJ',      '12/14/2010 12:00:00 AM',      'Coffee')
    , ('NJ',      '12/14/2010 1:15:00 PM',       'Beers')
    , ('NJ',      '12/14/2010 3:45:00 AM',       'Cream')
    , ('NJ',      '12/14/2010 1:45:00 PM',       'Water');
GO



IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('udfProductsSoldInDateRange'))
    DROP FUNCTION udfProductsSoldInDateRange;
GO

CREATE FUNCTION udfProductsSoldInDateRange (@StartDate AS DATE, @EndDate AS DATE, @State CHAR(2))
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Result INT;
    SELECT 
        @Result = COUNT(*) 
    FROM ProductTest 
    WHERE CAST(ProductTest.DateSold AS DATE) BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
        AND ProductTest.InState = @State;

    RETURN @Result;
END;
GO

DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '20101210';

DECLARE @EndDate1 DATE = '20101211';
DECLARE @EndDate2 DATE = '20101212';
DECLARE @EndDate3 DATE = '20101213';
DECLARE @EndDate4 DATE = '20101214';

SELECT
    InState
    , dbo.udfProductsSoldInDateRange(@StartDate, @EndDate1, InState) AS [To 12/11]
    , dbo.udfProductsSoldInDateRange(@StartDate, @EndDate2, InState) AS [To 12/12]
    , dbo.udfProductsSoldInDateRange(@StartDate, @EndDate3, InState) AS [To 12/13]
    , dbo.udfProductsSoldInDateRange(@StartDate, @EndDate4, InState) AS [To 12/14]
FROM ProductTest
GROUP BY InState
ORDER BY InState

-- Or if you don't want to make the function, just run this query and hardcode your values.
SELECT
    InState
    , COUNT(*) AS ItemsSold
FROM ProductTest
WHERE CAST(ProductTest.DateSold AS DATE) BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate3
GROUP BY InState
ORDER BY InState
```